# Can you find the coefficient of x^r in a generating function if r is a negative number?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

> Find the coefficient of $x^8$ in $(x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)^5$.

I pulled the $x^2$ out to make it 
$$\left[x^2(1 + x + x^2 + x^3)\right]^5$$ 
and then 
$$x^{10}(1  + x + x^2 + x^3)^5$$
But then when I subtract the $x^{10}$ from the $x^8$ 
I get $x^{-2}$. Can I still find this coefficient or does it not work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’ve discovered is that there is no $x^8$ term in $(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^5$: the smallest exponent that appears when you multiply everything out is $10$. So the coefficient of $x^8$ is ... ?

Comment: would that make it 0?

Comment: @user4343563: It would indeed.